# Fibonacci sequence, number of trees, probability

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

How can I prove that the numbers of orderings described below are Fibonacci numbers?

We are given $p_1, \dots , p_n > 0$ such that each $p_i= \frac{1}{2^k}$ for $i \in \{1, \dots , n\}, \ \ k \in \mathbb{N}$  and $$p_1 + \dots +p_n = 1$$ and the sequence $(p_1, ..., p_n)$ must be non rising.

I've computed the numbers of such orderings for small $n$.

And for $n=1$ we have only one possibility: $(1)$ For $n=2$ we have $$\left(\frac{1}{2} , \frac{1}{2}\right)$$ so also one possibility. For $n=3$ we have one: $$\left( \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4}\right)$$ for $ n=4$ I've found $2$: $$\left( \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{8}, \frac{1}{8}\right) \ \ \left( \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4}\right)$$ for $n=5$ we have 3: $$\left( \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{8}, \frac{1}{16}, \frac{1}{16}\right) \ \ \left( \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{8}, \frac{1}{8}, \frac{1}{8}, \frac{1}{8}\right) \ \ \left( \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{8}, \frac{1}{8}\right)$$ for $n=6$ I have $5$:

$$\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{8}, \frac{1}{16}, \frac{1}{32}, \frac{1}{32} \right) \ \ \left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{16}, \frac{1}{16}, \frac{1}{16}, \frac{1}{16} \right) \ \  \ \\ \left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{8}, \frac{1}{8}, \frac{1}{8}, \frac{1}{16}, \frac{1}{16} \right) \ \ \left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{8}, \frac{1}{16}, \frac{1}{16} \right), \left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{8}, \frac{1}{8}, \frac{1}{8}, \frac{1}{8} \right)   $$ and so on. But I don't know how to justify it mathematically, that means - how to find an occurence relation for different $n$s .

Comment: What is your example for $n=3$ apart from $\frac12+\frac14+\frac14$ and for $n=4$ apart from $\frac12+\frac14+\frac18+\frac18$ and $\frac14+\frac14+\frac14+\frac14$?

Comment: @Henry Of course you are right. I've rewritten it wrong here from my notebook. Could you help me prove the statement?

Comment: Are you certain the sequence is definitely Fibonacci? It appears to be larger than that. I've been trying to force it to be Fibonacci, by realizing sequences beginning with $(\frac{1}{2}, \dots)$ are counted by the previous term and sequences beginning with $(\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4}, \dots)$ are counted by the term two positions behind. But eventually we get terms beginning with $(\frac{1}{8}, \dots)$ and we need to account for those.

Comment: @E.Lim I see. Well I've only computed the values for a few $n$ and I may have made some mistakes. Have you found a connection between $n$ and the number if such non rising sequences?

Comment: @E.Lim: there are also cases like $\frac14 + \frac18 + \frac18 + \frac18 + \frac18 + \frac18 + \frac18$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the Fibonacci sequence, as it starts $1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 16, \ldots $ so has too many examples when $n \ge 7$.  For $7$ parts, the examples are:

- $ \frac1{2}  + \frac1{4}  + \frac1{8}  + \frac1{16}  + \frac1{32}  + \frac1{64}  + \frac1{64} $
- $ \frac1{2}  + \frac1{4}  + \frac1{8}  + \frac1{32}  + \frac1{32}  + \frac1{32}  + \frac1{32} $
- $ \frac1{2}  + \frac1{4}  + \frac1{16}  + \frac1{16}  + \frac1{16}  + \frac1{32}  + \frac1{32} $
- $ \frac1{2}  + \frac1{8}  + \frac1{8}  + \frac1{8}  + \frac1{16}  + \frac1{32}  + \frac1{32} $
- $ \frac1{2}  + \frac1{8}  + \frac1{8}  + \frac1{16}  + \frac1{16}  + \frac1{16}  + \frac1{16} $
- $ \frac1{4}  + \frac1{4}  + \frac1{4}  + \frac1{8}  + \frac1{16}  + \frac1{32}  + \frac1{32} $
- $ \frac1{4}  + \frac1{4}  + \frac1{4}  + \frac1{16}  + \frac1{16}  + \frac1{16}  + \frac1{16} $
- $ \frac1{4}  + \frac1{4}  + \frac1{8}  + \frac1{8}  + \frac1{8}  + \frac1{16}  + \frac1{16} $
- $ \frac1{4}  + \frac1{8}  + \frac1{8}  + \frac1{8}  + \frac1{8}  + \frac1{8}  + \frac1{8} $

The sequence is described by [OEIS $A002572$](https://oeis.org/A002572) with several references.

Empirically it seems that number of examples with $n$ parts is slightly more than about $$0.141853\ldots \times 1.794147\ldots^n$$

Comment: Thank you very much! However, I haven't found any formula or a way to calculate the numbers of such partitions, given $n$. Is there any?

Comment: They are not trivial, but the following links from OEIS look as if they have formulae: http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=3082580&fileId=S0013091500021945 http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X10003432 http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf (page 200) http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X87901373 http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019995872901490 http://arxiv.org/abs/1108.5964

Comment: Ok, I'll read that, thanks again :)